# Custom table output cleanup - formatting array-valued properties

Tags: powershell, formatting

My one liner looks like:

```
get-vm vm* |select name, numcpu,memoryGB,@{e={$_|get-harddisk |select capacityGB};l="disk"}
```

My output looks like:

```
Name            NumCpu MemoryGB disk
----            ------ -------- ----
vm1             4      96       {@{CapacityGB=60}, @{CapacityGB=300}, @{CapacityGB=200}}
vm2             8      98       {@{CapacityGB=50}, @{CapacityGB=450}}
vm3             8      96       {@{CapacityGB=200}, @{CapacityGB=50}, @{CapacityGB=300}}
vm4             2      12       {@{CapacityGB=100}, @{CapacityGB=50}}
```

How can I clean up that output to only show the disk size numbers and not all the `@{capacityGB= }`?

Comment: What output were you expecting? (Hint: How should PowerShell output when there is more than one disk?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate fix is to use `select -ExpandProperty capacityGB`:

```
get-vm vm* |select name, numcpu,memoryGB,@{e={$_|get-harddisk |select -ExpandProperty capacityGB};l="disk"}
```

This would result in something like:

```
Name            NumCpu MemoryGB disk
----            ------ -------- ----
vm1             4       96      {60, 300, 200}
```

`-ExpandProperty` means that only the specified property's *value* should be returned, not a *custom object* that has the specified property, which is what something like `@{CapacityGB=60}` represents in your output.

Note that PowerShell:

- uses enclosing `{ ... }` to represent an array-valued property
- with the individual elements represented as they would be if you cast them to `[string]` (or used them in a double-quoted string).

If the output is for *display* only, and you want different formatting, build your own output string inside the script block, as shown in [Frode F.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42402602/45375).

Answer (score 3):

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to extract the value of the property. That will remove `@{CapacityGB=` which is shown because you have an array of objects with a `CapacityGB`-property. Ex:

```
Get-VM vm* | Select-Object Name, NumCPU,MemoryGB,@{l="Disk";e={$_ | Get-HardDisk | Select-Object -Expand CapacityGB}}

Name NumCPU MemoryGB Disk          
---- ------ -------- ----          
vm1       4       96 {60, 300, 200}
vm2       8       98 {50, 450}
```

To remove the remaining `{ }` which represents an array of values, you can combine them to a string:

```
Get-VM vm* | Select-Object Name, NumCPU,MemoryGB,@{l="Disk";e={($_ | Get-HardDisk | Select-Object -Expand CapacityGB) -join ', '}}

Name NumCPU MemoryGB Disk        
---- ------ -------- ----        
vm1       4       96 60, 300, 200
vm2       8       98 50, 450
```

Or if you only want this for console output, you could add linebreaks, but this requires `Format-Table -Wrap` to display properly in PowerShell

```
#Output from Format-Table is not exportable. It just results in formatdata-objects
Get-VM vm* |
Select-Object Name, NumCPU, MemoryGB, @{l="Disk";e={($_ | Get-HardDisk | Select-Object -Expand CapacityGB) -join "`n" }} |
Format-Table -Wrap

Name NumCPU MemoryGB Disk      
---- ------ -------- ----      
vm1       4       96 60        
                     300       
                     200       
vm2       8       98 50        
                     450
```